# using for loops with time series data

Tags: python, for-loop, time-series

So I need some help analyzing some time series data using for loops.
for my class i am using shark tag data for a final project. I have linked an image of what the data looks like below :

[image: data table]

so each shark has its own transmitter number, what i need to do is loop through each shark so that i can count how many times individual sharks were detected at the different receiver stations (so right now we can see that shark A69-1105-78 was at receiver "Electric Beach" for a count 5 times-- need to do this for all 52 sharks ). then my professor wants me to identify the 1st and last time each sharks was detected at each station to get an idea of the movement..
Im in desperate need of help- this project is due friday.I don't really understand how Id go about using the for loop to do this analysis

Comment: You're using pandas, right?

Comment: The data you have attached, is it a file or a pandas `dataframe`?

Comment: @marmikshah i am using pandas, yes

Comment: @MayankPorwal i am reading in a csv using pd.read_csv

Comment: Well, then you can first take a look at `groupby` function
Something like. `df.groupby('Transmitter')['Receiver Station'].apply(list)`

Comment: @marmikshah is there a way to do first and last for each segment? meaning if shark #1 went to receiver #1 from 4pm-6pm and was detected 10 times, then went to receiver #4 from 610-7 and was detected 17 times, it then went back to receiver #1 from 8-10 detected 20 times- how can i do first and last detection in each segment?? and how would i put this in a for loop so it can be done to all the sharks?

Comment: @marmikshah please see question above, i am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1.) Count how many times individual sharks were detected at the different receiver stations:

```
df.groupby(['Transmitter','Receiver Station']).size()
```

2.) 1st and last time each sharks was detected at each station:

First time occurrence:

```
df.groupby(['Transmitter','Receiver Station'])['Time_Date'].min()
```

Last time occurrence:

```
df.groupby(['Transmitter','Receiver Station'])['Time_Date'].max()
```

#### For each segment's first and last occurrence, use your df's `Date` column in groupby and find `min` and `max` of `Time` column:

```
df.groupby(['Transmitter','Receiver Station','Date'])['Time'].min()
df.groupby(['Transmitter','Receiver Station','Date'])['Time'].max()
```

Comment: is there a way to do first and last for each segment? meaning if shark #1 went to receiver #1 from 4pm-6pm and was detected 10 times, then went to receiver #4 from 610-7 and was detected 17 times, it then went back to receiver #1 from 8-10 detected 20 times- how can i do first and last detection in each segment?? and how would i put this in a for loop so it can be done to all the sharks?

Comment: please see question above as i am still stuck.

Comment: @LaurenAnnArnold Got it. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: it does work but not fully. We ended up figuring out the code for the most part, thank you for your help!!